# Azure Devops Tests Summary of Tests tab doesn't include the results of integration-tests, only the unit-test results

Tags: spring, azure, maven, azure-devops, integration-testing

I noticed that the Tests Summary section only includes the results of unit tests. But it doesn't include the integration-test results, which we need because those can fail the build too.

We are using Maven. Based on the build logs below, it seems the test results are published after the package phase, before maven-failsafe-plugin runs:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 134, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ xvab-web ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/vsts/work/1/s/xvab-web/target/xvab-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.1.0:repackage (repackage) @ xvab-web ---
[INFO] Layout: ZIP
[INFO] Replacing main artifact /home/vsts/work/1/s/xvab-web/target/xvab-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar with repackaged archive, adding nested dependencies in BOOT-INF/.
[INFO] The original artifact has been renamed to /home/vsts/work/1/s/xvab-web/target/xvab-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0:integration-test (default) @ xvab-web ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
```

Tests Summary section attached:

[image: Confusion: build failed but tests passed]

I am not able to find a solution in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-continuous-test-results-after-build?view=azure-devops), I want the tests summary to include the output of both unit and integration tests.

Comment: You can run maven build and package on your local machine and check whether you can see the result of integration-tests. If you can see it, upload the test result file to Azure DevOps and publish it directly via [PublishTestResults@2 - Publish Test Results v2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-test-results-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=trx%2Ctrxattachments%2Cyaml) and then check if you can see the integration-tests in the pipeline test sumamry.

Comment: This worked, thanks! If you want to you can post this as the answer and I will accept it.
After adding the below step I was able to see the results of integration tests as well as unit tests:

              - task: PublishTestResults@2
                inputs:
                  testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
                  testResultsFiles: |
                    **/xvab-web/target/failsafe-reports/TEST-*.xml
                    **/xvab-web/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
                  failTaskOnFailedTests: true
                  mergeTestResults: true

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT tagging you here to get notified.

Comment: It's great to know my suggestion works for you. I have posted it below. In order to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept my answer below according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a task [PublishTestResults@2 - Publish Test Results v2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-test-results-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=trx%2Ctrxattachments%2Cyaml) in your pipeline to publish your test result.

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    mergeTestResults: true
    failTaskOnFailedTests: true
```